# Replacing words in vba

Tags: vba, excel

how do I replace words in vba? For example I have a column of words but some ends with U and E and I want to remove the U and E, how do I do that?

```
Cells.Replace What:="/*-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I used this to change for example "AAA/&-" to "AAA". How do I do the same for "AAA U" to "AAA", I cant use the same formula, as "U" is a common letter? My columns of words consist of about 20+ different words that ends with U so I can't hardcode the word as well.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: `Cells.Replace " U", "", xlPart` if no words contain " U" before the end

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the cells, examining the last character of each one:

```
Sub Remove_E_and_U()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            If Right(v, 1) = "U" Or Right(v, 1) = "E" Then
                r.Value = Mid(v, 1, Len(v) - 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To restrict the macro to columns **F** through **H**, replace:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

with:

```
Range("F:H").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! It worked! But how can I keep it to only removing the E and U in column F to column H only?

Comment: @yeocs93  See **EDIT#1**

Comment: What if I want to create a table in the activesheet say Range (A3:B7) and enter all the "U" or "E" etc into each cell so that they can be changed in future, how do I modify the code?

Comment: If Right(v, 1) = Range(A3) or Right(v, 1) = Range(A4) .... I tried doing this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe regex?

```
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

Pattern = "(\w+\s)(U|E)"
replacement = "$1"
RE.Pattern = Pattern

Regex = RE.Replace(Range("A1").Value, replacement)
```

EDIT; This will keep the space `AAA` if you want to remove the space move the `\s` part of the Pattern to the other () like: `"(\w+)(\sU)"`